# null model when editing a telerik grid dropdown

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik grid that shows a drop-down when editing. The problem is, that I can't set the selected value on the drop-down - it says null Reference. Here is the code:

Controller

```
 public ActionResult MultipleGm(long Id)
    {
      LoadGmData(Id);
      List<gm_select> LoadedGm = GmFunctions.GetGms(Id);
      return View("Gm/MultipleGm", LoadedGm);
    }
    public void LoadGameData(long Id)
    {
      ViewBag.Tms = GmFunctions.GetTms(Id);
     }
```

Model

```
public partial class gm_select
{
    [UIHint("NameID")]
    public name_id { get; set; }
}
public partial class name_id 
{
    public long id;
    public string name;
}
```

View

```
@model List<gm_select>
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Names")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.name_id);
         })
```

DisplayTemplate

```
@model name_id
@Model.name
```

EditorTemplate

```
@model name_id
@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
     .Name("DropDownList")
     .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewBag.Teams,"id","name", Model.name))
  )
```

The problem is here in the code **Model.name**, I don't know way this is null. If I change the code to

```
@model name_id
@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
     .Name("DropDownList")
     .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewBag.Tms,"id","name"))
  )
```

It works, but when editing it doesn't show the correct selected item.

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following online examples which show a similar setup:

1. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/serveredittemplates
2. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientedittemplates

If they don't help consider opening a forum thread in the Telerik forums and sending a short sample application.